# Dell PowerEdge T110 ii Video Sluggish on Ubuntu 12.4LTS

Tags: teamviewer, gpu-driver

I installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.4 LTS on Dell PowerEdge T110 ii and it works fine except very sluggish mouse movements and inability to use Teamviewer. I feel there is an issue with the graphic cars drivers. How can I get that resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find the Dell PowerShell T110 ii  I can only find a Dell PowerEdge T110 ii. And that is a server, not a desktop machine. Are you sure about the model. ?

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu has reached the [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Please, update your distro to a new version. For help with this, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/110477/62483)

Comment: Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: No still, you shouldn't use `10.04` but 12.04 onwards. Check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases to know what versions are still supported for desktops.

Comment: Changing the Ubuntu version from 10 to 12 in your question doesn't make it on topic. You need to actually **upgrade** to 12.04 or later.

Comment: Sorry again. I am having the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have erroneously stated 10.4. I will correct it in the topic as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dell Poweredge T110 II  has a Matrox G200eW videocard with a whopping 8 MB videomemory. (that is 200 times smaller than the average consumer computer)

Ubuntu is sluggish because it has to emulate the 3D desktop on a 2D videocard and it is also not able to display everything because of the very tiny amount of video memory.

Don't expect Ubuntu Desktop to run on that. You better settle for Lubuntu or Xubuntu if you want to have a working Desktop.

This computer was never designed as a desktop computer but as a server (minimal or no GUI intended in the design).

Comment: Can we add a separate video card and solve the issue?

Comment: That is absolutely a very good idea